# Unable to access published webapi from outside windows domain

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

My network environment is a follows. I have a Windows Server 2016 domain controller and a member server.
On the member server I have IIS and Visual Studio 2019 installed.

I created a webapi in VS2019 that writes data to a SQL server. I am using Postman for testing.
Everyting works fine when I runt postman on the member server and on the DC. However when I run postman from my workstation which is NOT a member of the domain I get error 500.

Below is a snipit from the IIS log.
192.168.100.222 is my DC
192.168.100.10 is my stand alone Windows 10 workstation.

2020-11-02 15:31:13 ::1 POST /api/SleepDiary sSleepGuy=guy2@there.com&sPilotName=Rick%20Doe 80 - ::1 PostmanRuntime/7.26.5 - 204 0 0 834

2020-11-02 15:31:52 192.168.100.223 POST /api/SleepDiary sSleepGuy=guy2@there.com&sPilotName=Rick%20Doe 80 - 192.168.100.222 PostmanRuntime/7.26.5 - 204 0 0 16

2020-11-02 15:32:14 192.168.100.223 POST /api/SleepDiary sSleepGuy=guy1@there.com&sPilotName=Rick%20Doe 80 - 192.168.100.10 PostmanRuntime/7.26.8 - 500 0 0 225

Comment: 500.0 indicates unhandled exception in your own code or the web framework. To learn why you have to debug your web app.

Comment: Hi Lex Thank you for replying to ma post. I do disagree with you though. Since the api works fine on any computer that is part of the window domain, makes  me think that this is a permission issue.

Comment: Even if that’s a permission issue, you have to debug your web app to learn more. IIS returns 40x when its own code experience permission issues., not 500.

Comment: Hello Lex. You were right. I configured debugging in the iis server and it turned out that I had a spelling mistake in the Postman app. Thank you so much :-)